# Fetching Google Advertising ID using in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

In my Phonegap Application, I have to fetch Google Advertising ID. For this I have been trying with some plugins which are not working properly. Can any one suggest some plugin for getting Google Advertising ID using phonegap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use this app (or another similar app - several apps exist) on the device you want the ID from:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.t3d.detectdevice

Comment: This is not a solution to get Google Advertising ID from a Phonegap app.